# Computer only starts when I insert, then withdraw, my USB drive

Tags: boot, usb-flash-drive, bootable-media

So, for some time my desktop has been having infrequent fits, after which it refuses to start. It hangs right before it tells me about its memory stuff (I don't really know any of the technical names). However, if I insert a specific USB thumb drive before booting, it hangs slightly after the aforementioned point, and prompts me to remove the drive. This may have something to do with the USB having been previously used as a bootable disk.

I realised, then, that if I leave the USB in for long enough for the computer to boot past the initial freeze point, then remove it before the second, the problem never occurs. Why does this happen, and/or how can I avoid it?

PS:
The memory stuff I mentioned earlier; It freezes just before it would normally print the message `Memory Runs at Flex Memory Mode`, which is basically my way of checking that the computer will boot or not.

Comment: I would: 1) Verify each of my offline data backups.   2) Reinstall the OS.   3) Restore data.

Comment: Ouch. Yeah, I probably would, but that was what I tried last time (about a year ago), when I was running windows; and I gave up and installed linux. It reduced the frequency and severity of the problem, but it has again crept back.  
I feel like this could be a hardware problem, but if it comes down to it I probably would reinstall everything just to make sure.

Answer (score -1):

I can't comment because of insufficient points, but you must have changed boot order of drives like first Removable USB drive, then SATA drives etc.

Try resetting your Boot order or make sure the SATA drive is on top where the windows is installed.

If you don't know how to do this I can explain, if you dont want to do this you can reset BIOS by entering BIOS going to last tab/page and doing reset to default.

ASSUMING THAT THIS IS THE PROBLEM. This may not be the correct answer to your question.

Comment: "Try resetting your Boot order or make sure the SATA drive is on top where the windows is installed."

Oh, I'm not running windows. I'm a Linux girl.

Comment: @Zoey: When Sam wrote "windows" he meant "your operating system" and when I wrote that I meant "your primary operating system" (if you have several installed on the same bootable SATA drive)

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)